# Why i can not get value select in mozilla?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

**[Page on site](http://astralux.biz/service/)**

[image]

We have script:

```
<select onchange="PartnersChangeValueSelect(this.value)" id="PartnersChangeValueSelect"> 
<option value="0">Выберите категорию</option>
<option value="1677">Швейные машины</option> 
<option value="1730" selected="selected">Оверлоки</option> 
<option value="1919">Сертификаты</option> 
</select>

function PartnersChangeValueSelect(val){

obj = $('#ModelFiles_' + val);
alert($("#PartnersChangeValueSelect option:selected").val());
$("#PartnersChangeValueSubSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$('#DivSelectInPartnersSubCategoryCatalog').hide();
if(val == '1677'){$('#DivSelectInPartnersSubCategoryCatalog').show();}
else if(val == '1730' || val == '1733' || val == '1919'){obj.show();}/
}
```

We have problem when want get value select in mozilla(test on page site please).

My steps:

1) Select "Швейные машины" // value select "PartnersChangeValueSelect" is true

2) select "Оверлоки" // value select "PartnersChangeValueSelect" is true

3) again select "Швейные машины" //value select "PartnersChangeValueSelect" is error

4) again select "Оверлоки" //value select "PartnersChangeValueSelect" is error

Tell me please why i have this bag in mozilla and how remove bag?

Comment: IF you are using jQuery, Why are you not binding event using it? And to fetch value simple `$("#PartnersChangeValueSelect").val()` will do the job. And You have additional `/` at the end of function

Comment: If possible try to reproduse same in a jsfiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/yuf2s/1/ check this fiddle its work for me

Comment: please not use jsfiidle - see on site please

Comment: Why not using jsFiddle?

Comment: @Martin becouse bag with mozilla when script used on site, not on jsfiddle

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to one web site only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove plugin **selected.js** he is block script in mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to write your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yQKV/) and applied events in a more "jQuery way". I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8yQKV/) will help you.

```
$('#PartnersChangeValueSelect').change(function(){
   $selected = $(this).find(":selected");
   selectedValue = $selected.val();
   obj = $('#ModelFiles_' + selectedValue);
   alert(selectedValue);
   $selected.removeAttr("selected");

   $('#DivSelectInPartnersSubCategoryCatalog').hide();
   if (selectedValue == '1677') {
       $('#DivSelectInPartnersSubCategoryCatalog').show();
   } else if (selectedValue == '1730' || selectedValue == '1733' || selectedValue == '1919') {
       obj.show();
   }
});
```

Comment: please not use js fiidle - see on site please

Answer (score 0):

Works for me...

```
<select id="PartnersChangeValueSelect"> 
   <option value="0">Выберите категорию</option>
   <option value="1677">Швейные машины</option> 
   <option value="1730" selected="selected">Оверлоки</option> 
   <option value="1919">Сертификаты</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function PartnersChangeValueSelect(val) {
    obj = $('#ModelFiles_' + val);
    alert($("#PartnersChangeValueSelect option:selected").val());
    $("#PartnersChangeValueSubSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    $('#DivSelectInPartnersSubCategoryCatalog').hide();
    if (val == '1677') {
        $('#DivSelectInPartnersSubCategoryCatalog').show();
    } else if (val == '1730' || val == '1733' || val == '1919') {
        obj.show();
    }
}

$('#PartnersChangeValueSelect').change(function() {
    PartnersChangeValueSelect($(this).val());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4Gkt/)

Comment: please not use js fiidle - see on site please